# Actual Classification re Nielsen-Thurston Theorem (how to)?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

according to Nielsen -Thurston Classification:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Thurston_classification

If $S$ is compact and orientable surface, then any homeomorphism is isotopic to  (at least  one) of
three classes of maps:

i ) Periodic

ii) Reducible

iii) Pseudo Anosov.

But the method does not seem to be constructive, i.e., how do we tell, given a

specific homeomorphism $ h: S \rightarrow S$ , whether $S$ belongs to one or more

of the classes? Do we actually test whether $h$ itself is periodic, i.e., $h^n=Id$ , for some integer $n$ , or whether $h$ itself fixes non-essential curves, etc.? If not, how do we otherwise determine this fact? Are these properties "robust" under isotopy, i.e., if $h$ satisfies $h^n=id$ , is $h$ necessarily periodic, and if g fixes a set of inessential curves, is g then necessarily reducible?

Thanks.

I imagine if we have a nice expression for $MCG(S)$ , e.g., like in the case of the
2-tours $T^2:= S^1 \times S^1 $, maybe we can use some linear algebraic techniques, but how do we classify homeomorphisms otherwise? Or maybe there are canonical choices for representatives of each $h$ in $MCG(S)$ ?

Comment: Carlson has a book on this, maybe you can look it up.

Comment: Any chance you have the name of the book, please?

Comment: He has only a few books, so search Casson and Thurston gives you the result (http://www.boomerangbooks.com.au/Automorphisms-of-Surfaces-After-Nielsen-and-Thurston/Andrew-J-Casson/book_9780521349857.htm). Sorry for the typo earlier.

Comment: The question in your title does not agree with the question in the body of your post.  There is of course oodles of uses of the Thurston classification.  For example, you can describe when two mapping classes commute in terms of it.  You can describe when a bundle over the circle is a hyperbolic 3-manifold in terms of it.  And so on.

Comment: You're right, let me change the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an algorithm by Bestiva and Handel to determine the Nielsen-Thurston representative from other descriptions. See [these](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2946562?uid=3739560&uid=2486944703&uid=2&uid=3&uid=3739256&uid=60&sid=21105527244033) [two](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938394E00099) papers.

The robust descriptions which are preserved by isotopy are: (1) periodic means $h^n \simeq id$ for some $n$ (isotopic, not equal), and (2) reducible means (not periodic and) $h$ fixes the homotopy class of some essential closed curve, and then (3) pseudo-Anosov is everything else. This last is not particularly illuminating, and one way of viewing the content of Thurston's theorem is that all of these have a nice representative that has a particular geometric structure. The papers I linked above show how to take a description of a mapping class and determine the nice representative (whether it be the exactly periodic map with $h^n = id$, or a map exactly fixing a curve (as a set), or the nice pseudo-Anosov representative).

On $T^2$, the classification is simple. The (orientation-preserving) mapping class group of the torus is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and given $A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the trace of $A$ determines whether it is periodic ($|\operatorname{tr}(A)| < 2$, i.e. complex eigenvalues; also $\pm I$ would fit here), reducible (not $\pm I$ and $|\operatorname{tr}(A)| = 2$), or Anosov ($|\operatorname{tr}(A)| > 2$, i.e. two distinct real eigenvalues).

Comment: Thanks, by robustness I meant whether the properties are preserved by isotopy, i.e., if h~g in MCG(S) and h^n=Id, does it follow that g^n=Id, or at least there is some m with g^m=Id? Similar for reducible, if h~g and h fixes the homotopy class of an essential curve, is the same true for g, etc.?

Comment: @user203864 Yes, that's how I meant it as well. The answer to your question is a decisive no. The correct robust (i.e. preserved by isotopy) condition would be if $h \simeq g$ and $h^n \simeq \mathrm{id}$ then $g^n \simeq \mathrm{id}$, which is trivial.

Comment: Ah, never mind, if you define $h^n \simeq Id $, then this is obviously closed under isotopy. How about pseudo-anosov, reducible, are these preserved under isotopy?

Comment: @user203864 For reducible, the condition I give above is preserved under isotopy, and pseudo-Anosov is everything else, so that's preserved under isotopy because the first two are (but, as I said, that description is not particularly illuminating).

Comment: But how can this be robust if there are maps that , if I understood correctly, may belong to more than one class?

Comment: @user203864 I included "not periodic" in my definition of reducible. There's no overlap, given that. The way to view this is that periodic and pseudo-Anosov are certain (incompatible) geometric structures, and reducible means you can break down the map into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the answer of @aes, your guesses at robusteness properties are too strong to be true. However, there are weaker robustness properties that are quite useful.

Here is a weaker robustness property which is satisfied by a pseudo-Anosov mapping class.

It is not true, of course, that if $g$ is a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism and $g$ is isotopic to $h$ then $h$ is a pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism.

However, what is true is that if $g$ and $h$ are both pseudo-Anosov homeomorphisms of $S$, and if $g$ and $h$ are isotopic to each other, then they are isotopic *through pseudo-Anosov homeomorphisms*. In other words, there is an isotopy from $g$ to $h$ such that at all moments of the isotopy the homeomorphism is pseudo-Anosov. In fact it is even stronger than that: there exists an isotopy $K_t(x)$, $(x,t) \in S \times [0,1]$, such that $K_0$ is the identity map and such that $h(x) = K_1^{-1} \circ g \circ K_1(x)$. The isotopy through pseudo-Anosov homeomorphisms is then given by 
$$(x,t) \mapsto K_t^{-1} \circ g \circ K_t(x)
$$
This is proved in the book on the [Orsay seminar of Thurston's work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691147353), which is an excellent source to address many foundational issues related to your overall question.